# Why are other modules besides MIMEApplication needed for the stmplib module?

Tags: python

I have a misunderstanding.

In smtplib I can attach a text file, image file, zip, or any other file type by importing the right module.

For example to attach a text file, I need to do:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

to_attach = MIMEText(temp_file.read())
to_attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='xxx.txt')
msg.attach(to_attach)
```

And for images:

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
```

And so on....

But why do I need those different modules when I have the `MIMEApplication` module?

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
```

I succeeded in sending  any type of file (zip, apk, png etc...) with this module to my email...

So, what is the purpose of the other modules, if there is any?

Comment: MIMEImage automatically sets the Content-Type header and sets the subtype to an Image one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mime type tells the receiving email client what file type is attached. The `smtplib` modules do this by setting the `Content-Type` header of the mail attachment.

The "Application" mimetype is the lowest common denominator type. It tells the email client that the data is a binary file with no particular interpretation. Normally the only option for unknown binary data is to offer to save it to disk. On the other hand if some binary data is marked as being an Image, the client may show it in the email, or offer to open an image viewer. Your email client may be able to read some of the binary data and identify that a particular binary attachment is in fact an image (for example) but you should not depend on this.

Marking data as text also allows the client to be smart about converting line endings (as different operating systems have different conventions about which character or combination of characters mark the end of a line) Sending a text file as a binary application prevents this, but is not as bad as sending a binary file as text, which can cause corruption.

In short, it is best to send attachments with the right MIME type, to give the receiver the best chance of being able to handle them correctly.